# In Swift (Darwin), why does exit() take an Int32 instead of a UInt8?

Tags: swift, darwin

This complete Swift program gives an exit code of 255:

```
import Darwin
exit(-1)
```

When run from within Xcode I get `Program ended with exit code: 255`; or when compiled and run on the command line `echo $?` produces `255`; etc. At some point `Int32(-1)` is being truncated and interpreted as an unsigned 8-bit integer.

I don't know where this conversion happens (perhaps in Darwin somewhere or when the value is passed into the host shell or OS?), but since `exit()` is a Darwin library function (not a Swift language feature), which is already specific to the platform, why is it defined to take an `Int32` instead of a `UInt8`?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703741/basic-c-question-about-return-values or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435730/forked-child-exits-with-1-but-wexitstatus-gets-255.

Comment: @MartinR those two questions are about C, and this question is not about why does 255 pop out. It's about why is the `exit()` function in Swift is designed / defined as it is, rather than something more sensible for a Swift programmer (for example someone who has never done any other language). It seems distinctly non-swifty to me.

Comment: `exit()` is a C library function, and it does not matter if you call it from C or from Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's the standard C `exit` function, which has the following prototype:

```
void exit(int);
```

On your system that `int` is 32 bits so that's why Swift uses `Int32` for it.

The truncation happens somewhere inside the C `exit` function.

Comment: This may or may not be the reason - but if it is then it doesn't make sense from a library design point of view - why design a function in Swift to behave inconsistently with its own definition, just because "that's what C does" or "we're implementing it in C so we'll just inherit that behaviour"? If you make the design decision to adopt that behaviour for compatibility with shell scripts that expect 0-255 (because that's what C does) then surely you'd design and document your function to take a UInt8?

Comment: `exit` is not a Swift function and wasn't designed for Swift. It's just a C function you can call from Swift, like everything else in `Darwin`.

Comment: hrm.. ok - I guess that makes sense. If it's not actually intended as a Swift interface, but a mapping onto a C one. Still - I consider this poor interface design because when creating a mapping you should use the conventions/expectations of the calling language.